# Code update 2017

Tags: electrical

From what i get 2008 table 310.15{b}(6) is no longer code. I hear 310.15(b)(7) has replaced it. Trying to find out what is the  smallest size aluminum wire for 100 amp sup panel 10 feet away? That is the question and that is the wire type.Have had some answers.Some say #2 allowed and others say not allowed due to 310.15(b)(7). Also if you know a web page where i could read ((b)(7) would be helpful .thank you

Comment: So far had someone say #2 alum and one#1 alum

Comment: Funny thing about standards like NFPA’s national electrical code:  even though they are adopted as “law” in many places, they’re extremely hard to find online (and copyrighted.). Try your local public library as they likely have a recently updated copy, or at least an authoritative study guide.

Comment: Ya back when i was working took minutes to look up.

Comment: Actually NFPA will give you "free" access, and by "free" they mean you need to signup for an account, maintain *yet another* password to forget, leave your password on yet another server to get hacked, endure endless spam mail, and promise your first-born son will become an electrician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### #1 Al

Because 310.15(b)(7) doesn't have anything to do with subpanel feeder.  It's for wiring that is *in lieu of* service entrance wire, and performs that function.

This is NFPA's concession to the fact that power companies (who don't follow NEC, they follow a different code) are allowed to use smaller wire on the power drop to your house.

You are not allowed to use 310.15(b)(7) bonus 83% derate unless **all** the dwelling's electrical service flows through that wire  (because that serves the function of a service-entrance wire).  It's not allowed on subpanel runs.

---

Prior to 2014 NEC, 310.15(b)(7) was not stated as an 83% bonus derate.  It was expressed as a separate table, listing wire sizes and allowable ampacity for each.  On *that* table you see #2Al being allowed for 100A.  Naturally, people looking for wire size just dive right into NEC and look around for a table that states it.  Their eyes glaze over when they see the correct table 310.15b16, because it is a complex table to interpret and requires referring to the prose.  However, they found 310.15b7 and it *looked like* **exactly** what they're after - simple, straightforward, and even said "feeder"!  The prose disclaimed that, but nobody reads.

All good reasons to get rid of that table entirely...

Comment: Thank on 310-15{b)(7) got that.Is table 310-(b)(6) still in 2017 code? And if not what article or code number should i be looking for in 2017 code book ?#1 has been chosen  twice now. Also get #2

Comment: The table you are after is no longer in the Code as it was replaced by an 83% adjustment factor specified in running text in 310.15(B)(7) points 1 and 2 @RobertMoody

Comment: (Also note that the 310.15(b)(7) adjustment can apply after a main breaker, but only to feeders that feed an *entire dwelling unit*, such as the feeder from a multi-metermain to an individual apartment)

Comment: #1 seems to be answer.But  one other post says (b)(7) has nothing to do with sub panels.

Comment: Thanks again @ThreePhaseEel ...

Answer (score 2):

After much input a #1 aluminum is the wire needed for 100 amp sup panel 10 feet away from a 200 amp main per 2017 code standards. And a #2 is no longer code.Table 310-17(b)(6) has been removed.

Comment: To be more precise, #2 was never code.  It was a result of people *misapplying* table 310.15b7, which only applies to service entrances and was never applicable to subpanel feeder. People went there because at first glance the table seemed to fit, and it was the simple table people expected to find.  Nobody read the text of article 310.15b7!!